# Hash table as return type of a function in C++

Tags: c++, hashtable

I would like to know if I can use Hash table as a return type of a function in C++.
 :)

Comment: You can use _any_ copy-able type as a return value. Just be careful because it might incur copying of the whole table.

Comment: If you have a hash table type, and it can be copy constructed, then yes.

Comment: Yes it can be copied... thanks guys...

Comment: You need a copy constructor to return that object.

Comment: You should be passing back a pointer or reference to the hash table.  Otherwise it will eat up memory and take longer.

Comment: @Bob Bryan: NO. Never return a reference to a local variable. Also, we have move constructors now with C++11, and (N)RVO has existed in most compilers for a long time now. Just return the hash table by-value.

Comment: Upvoted because this was a legitimate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ standard library implementation of a hash table is `std::unordered_map` and yes, you can happily return it from a function:

```
std::unordered_map<X, Y> foo() {
  std::unordered_map<X, Y> map;
  return map;
}
```

It can be copied because it has a copy constructor<sup>†</sup>. If you implement your own hash table, it will also be returnable if it has a copy constructor.

<sup>† In C++11, a move constructor will be sufficient for the example given.</sup>