# c++ call a c# DLL with Hashtable parameter

Tags: c#, c++, hashtable, managed

I'm trying to call a C# DLL from C++ using CLI as this link: http://tom-shelton.net/index.php/2008/11/01/calling-managed-code-from-a-dll-created-in-visual-c-2008/

Everything seem be fine.

But if the C# function has got a Hashtable parameter, I don't know how to call it.
C# function like this:

```
public void DoSomething(Hashtable htb,int,string etc)
```

Please help me to how to use this kind of C# function in C++.

Best regards

John

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15114857/1714342

Comment: Post what you already have code wise, what you have tried, what didn't work etc.

Comment: map or unordered_map not work.
When I try to call<br/>
 
<code>unordered_map <string,string> htb;<br/>

<code>DoSomething(htb,int,string etc);<br/>

It issue error Error  error C2664: 'void DoSomething(System::Collections::Hashtable ^,int,string,etc)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::tr1::unordered_map<_Kty,_Ty>' to 'System::Collections::Hashtable ^'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use CLR option then your c++ code becomes managed code. so you can use

```
System::Collections::Hashtable
```

in your c++ code to use Hashtable

Answer (score 1):

After try some failed times, I decided to solve like this
I declare a class

```
Class WrappedWhateverClass
{
private:
gcroot <CSharpClass ^> _caller;
public:
    gcroot <Hashtable^> htb;
void WrappedWhateverClass()
int DoSomethinginC( int , string, etc);
}
```

In code, I call the C# DoSomething function:

```
void WrappedWhateverClass::WrappedWhateverClass()
{
htb = gcnew Hashtable();
}
int WrappedWhateverClass::DoSomethinginC( int i, string str, etc)
{
_caller->DoSomething(htb,i,str, etc);
}
```